# SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveSelection() broken

Tags: selection, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

In my Google Spreadsheet, I have a dialog to get some user input.  In the OK button handler, I have the following code to get the currently selected row:

```
sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
nRow = sheet.getActiveSelection().getRow();
```

This has worked fine for months, however now it always returns a row of 1 regardless of the actual selected row.

Please fix.

Answer (score 0):

Nasty. Me too. There's an open issue on the tracker for this: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1476